# Komodo Edit 7 Run button is disabled

Tags: windows, perl, 64-bit, disabled-control, komodoedit

I have installed Komodo Edit 7. I am trying to run a simple Perl script. In the Run Command popup box I have chosen Run as "%F", but the Run button remains disabled. Even after choosing different options, it always remains disabled. It works fine on my 32 bit windows machine. The problem is with a 64 bit windows machine. Please let me know how to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting purposes, try running something simpler such as a Google search:

- [Google Run Command](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/8.0/tutorial/tourlet_googrun.html)